# BIRT Report Viewer in Tomcat works with toolbar disabled, but fails with it enabled. Any ideas what's going on?

Tags: java, tomcat, birt

We have a Tomcat webapp, with BIRT reports in it. Offhand, I don't know what version of BIRT we are using, but the problem is occurring on a single installation (one of many) that is in Tomcat 7.0.93, running on a 64-bit Java 8, on an IBM Midrange box.

On this one installation, if the BIRT viewer toolbar is disabled, the report runs just fine.

But if that toolbar is enabled, then we get a null pointer exception, producing this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.initRenderTask(RenderTask.java:153)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.(RenderTask.java:115)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.(RenderTask.java:98)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.createRenderTask(ReportEngineHelper.java:502)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine.createRenderTask(ReportEngine.java:515)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.createRenderTask(ReportEngineService.java:1635)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.renderReport(ReportEngineService.java:1537)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getPage(BirtViewerReportService.java:204)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.doExecution(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:237)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:250)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:136)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at com.touchtone.wintouch.WintouchFilter.doFilter(WintouchFilter.java:126)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at com.touchtone.wintouch.security.ContentSecurityPolicyFilter.doFilter(ContentSecurityPolicyFilter.java:186)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

This doesn't happen on any of our other installations, it's got our webapp team stumped.

Other potentially relevant information:
1. This doesn't appear to put *anything* in any of the Tomcat logs.
2. Neither the Tomcat manager, nor doing a WRKJVMJOB on the Tomcat server job, show any sign that the job is running short on heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Intercept the requests and compare them to find if there's a difference in headers, url parameters, etc. e.g. with Fiddler (or some other intercepting proxy, TLS debugging logs etc.).

Java 14 introduced a nice option to make NullPointerException more verbose but you need to enable it at startup with `-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages`.

If all else fails run Tomcat with remote debugging socket enabled and use e.g. Eclipse to set a breakpoint on any method or Exception you like to inspect.

Good luck!

Comment: After passing this on to my colleague in charge of the webapp, I heard back from him, and he had some ideas of his own for me to try. And I also heard from another colleague, who discovered something that shows up in the Chrome and Safari browser consoles (it doesn't show up in the Firefox browser console, though): "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)." Dunno whether that tells me anything I didn't already know, however.

Comment: I have since, at the direction of our webapp developer, enabled BIRT viewer logging on the "problem" installation, and captured log excerpts both with and without the toolbar enabled. There were dramatic differences in the logs, and hopefully my colleague will be able to make some sense of them.

Comment: Let's hope that the saying holds true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_devil_is_in_the_detail